# Is there way to enable iOS 6 design style for iOS 8?

Tags: user-interface, ios6, ios8

There is [UIUseLegacyUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19179958/751932)

But it does nothing with apps which started under iOS 8.

Is there other way to enable great iOS 6 design style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand there are no way to get iOS 6 design style if compiled with last version of Xcode.

For teaching proposal i describe one unrecommended way - fix build system:

1. install Xcode 5.1.1
2. install simulator 6.1 from Xcode 5.1.1 settings
3. download Xcode 4.6.3
4. copy iPhoneOS6.1.sdk from xcode 4.6.3 to xcode 5.1.1
5. rename iPhoneOS7.1.sdk to iPhoneOS7.1.sdk.disabled in the Xcode 5.1.1
6. use fixed Xcode 5.1.1 to compile code
7. Now app have look with great iOS 6 design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it's possible but it could be another way with hack of some framework functions which responsible for LegacyUI.

Use next links if you want to dig this way:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18220176/751932

https://github.com/facebook/fishhook